# How to install GD library on ubuntu server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

when I tried this line " apt-get install php7.0-gd php7.0" I got below error :
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
Depends: apache2-bin but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: apache2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I think you should go to askubuntu.

Comment: operation questions should be asked either over on askubuntu or superuser.com ... here on SO we focus on programming questions ... welcome to SO